# How do I compare two columns from different tables in different databases?

Tags: sql-server, metadata, information-schema

Say I have `Table_1` in `Database_1` with 25 Columns
and say I have `Table_2` in `Database_2` with 19 Columns
I want to compare the columns in `Table_1` and `Table_2` and output Columns that exist in `Table_1` but not in `Table_2`

I tried

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table_1'
EXCEPT
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table_2'
```

The problem is: If I am in Database_1 it only finds variables in Table_1 and return empty list for Table_2, if I am in Database_2 it only finds variables in Table_2 and returns empty list for Table_1. If say I am in Master, it returns empty list for both Table_1 and Table_2. How do I properly locate each table and their variables from one database?

Comment: Qualify the objects with the database name: `FROM Database_1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`... `FROM Database_2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`...

Comment: The same way as you would do any other cross-database query, use the fully qualified object name.

Comment: And use `sys.columns` if for no other reason than it means your code doesn't look like it's shouting at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any database object from any database *context* by fully qualifying the object name in the form of *database.schema.object*.

Using SQL Server you are better off using the *sys* schema, which (if performance matters) is better than using the *information_schema* schema.

So you can do

```
select name
from database_1.sys.columns
where object_id=object_id(N'database_1.sys.table_1')
except
select name
from database_2.sys.columns
where object_id=object_id(N'database_2.sys.table_2')
```